# Cleaning up UTF-16/CJK characters using PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16, cjk

I have some files on my computer that are in UTF-16, though this seems to be because of errors or corruption of the files rather than intent - they're supposed to be plain english. I uploaded one of these ([here](http://www.compareng.com/temp/watches.txt)). If I leave the encoding in Firefox (Viwe>Character Encoding) at UTF-8 then I get tons of gibberish (see [screenshot](http://www.compareng.com/temp/screen1.gif)). If I change the encoding to UTF-16 then it looks much better (see [screenshot2](http://www.compareng.com/temp/screen2.gif)), though there are still a bunch of CJK characters present.

I'd like to go through all these files and clean them up, and probably save them in utf-8 format (I'll be inserting the contents into a mysql table that uses the utf8_general_ci collation). Does anyone know how I can do this in automated fashion with PHP? I'd like to get rid of all the funky characters the file displays if you try to view it in UTF-8, and also all the CJK characters the display if you view in UTF-16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$txt = file_get_contents('watches.txt');
$txt = mb_convert_encoding($txt, 'UTF-8');
/*Nice regexp to strip non asci and non-printable chars*/
$txt = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+/S','',$txt);
$txt = preg_replace('/[^\x00-\x7F]+/S','',$txt);

echo $txt;
```